# Skip Checkout in Magento Only for Free Downloadable Products

Tags: magento-1.7

I am building a photography site using Magento CE 1.7.0.2. For the release, we plan to have a large number of downloadable products (images)--some for a fee and some for FREE.  We are hoping it is possible to use the normal Magento 'catalog' functionality to add categories with all (fee/FREE) products underneath.  Because some of the downloadable products are FREE it doesn't make sense to send users through the checkout when they try to download the FREE downloadable products, which brings me to my question:

Does anyone know how to modify the "add to cart" option to a "download" option ONLY for the FREE downloadable products?  We will still need to send the FEE products through the normal checkout process using the "add to cart" option?

If it is not possible to bypass the checkout process for FREE downloadable products using a direct download link, we are anticipating users to check out as a guest.  If the user checks out as a guest, we need modify Magento's current behavior.  Currently when a guest finishes the checks out process, a link is sent to the users email with a download link.  That link redirects the guest back to the site asking the guest to signin to download their product.  Unfortunately, the guest will not have an account to sign into because they checked out as a guest.

As an alternate option, We would want to changes Magento's behavior to allow the guest to check out as normal.  But when the guest is through with the checkout process, we need Magento to redirect the user to a page on the site where guest can download the link immediately.  We need to bypass the email process alltogether for guests purchaseing FREE downloadable products.

I have noticed that there is a 'free sample' option for downloadable products, but I would prefer not to use this if I can as I plan to use this field for its intended purpose when I add products other than images.

Thanks in advance,

Michael